# How to fix me51n user exit EXIT_SAPLMEREQ_010?

Tags: hook, abap, sap-erp

I have problem with me51n. I have an include in EXIT_SAPLMEREQ_010 that has a bunch of codes which we use it to receive errors. The problem of mine is;

-When i run me51n with required datas(mat. number, quantity, etc.) I get some errors which also includes the error that I'm expecting on the first time, however when i terminate me51n and run it again with the same exact data, i dont get my error. I have debugged it and put a break point on my include in EXIT_SAPLMEREQ_010 and it never gets to my breakpoint on the second run. (It gets to the breakpoint on the first run but not the second one).

I dont know how but with the same material it works fine later again at the first time but still on the second time i cant get the error again.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: could you check if this isn't related to the break point being inactive? After first setting the break point and calling me51n, remove the break point, set it again and start me51n again. And ideally you should set the break point in the exit function module itself and not in your include.

Comment: I dont think the problem is really about the breakpoint :(. Because for the specific material, I have to get 3 errors from me51n via my include and 4 other error from some other include. However, I can't get those 7 errors all the time. I get 7 at the first time but then when I try it again I get 4, It doesnt even go to my include (even tried with breakpoints). So I have no idea whats get triggered on background not to get to my include...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically problem was the developement system from the beginning  (sigh -_-). While having other errors rather than my errors, i assume my error gets stuck sometimes and never pop up because of the standard SAP procedure. So in test system (QA) me51n works perfectly when I'm just trying to have only my error.

Thanks for anyone who actually tried to help and I hope this might be useful sometime for someone in future.

Talha